# If $X_1, \ldots X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and we only observe $(X_1 - \bar{X}, \ldots, X_n - \bar{X})$, can we learn about $\mu$ or $\sigma^2$?

Tags: inference, likelihood

Suppose $X_1, \ldots X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and we only observe $(X_1 - \bar{X}, \ldots, X_n - \bar{X})$, such that each observed point is now mean centered. Can we still learn about $\mu$ or $\sigma^2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the variables are *de-meaned*, I don't think there is a way for you to get back the mean. However, you can make inferences about the variance since (by the way I'm assuming your samples are uncorrelated):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(X_i-\bar{X})&=\operatorname{var}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}X_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i\neq j} X_j\right)
\\&=\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2} \operatorname{var}(X_i) + \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i\neq j} \operatorname{var}(X_j)
\\&=\sigma^2\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}+\sigma^2\frac{(n-1)}{n^2}\\
&=\frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2
\end{align}

Comment: +1.  One rigorous way to support your statement about the mean being unidentifiable would be to observe that $\mu$ doesn't enter into the likelihood at all.